# Why prefer Yield over a simple return?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand use of Yield to enumerate the collection. I have written this basic code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Iterate iterate = new Iterate();
    foreach (int i in iterate.EnumerateList())
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", i);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

class Iterate
{
    public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateList()
    {
        List<int> lstNumbers = new List<int>();

        lstNumbers.Add(1);
        lstNumbers.Add(2);
        lstNumbers.Add(3);
        lstNumbers.Add(4);
        lstNumbers.Add(5);

        foreach (int i in lstNumbers)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

(1) What if I use simply `return i` instead of `yield return i`?

(2) What are the advantages of using Yield and when to prefer using it?

Edited **

In the above code, I think it is an overhead to use `foreach` two times. First in the `main function` and the second in the `EnumerateList` method.

Comment: `return i` would result in a compiler error; `i` is not `IEnumerable<int>`.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx

Comment: Just in case I remove IEnumerable<int> and simply loop through the collection instead of using IEnumerable with Yield.

Comment: @RKh Then it would return the first integer and never have an opportunity to return any of the others.

Comment: `yield return` can improve performance when you won't iterate through the entire collection. In this example, you may as well just `return lstNumbers`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `yield return i` makes this method an [*iterator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx).  It will create an `IEnumerable<int>` sequence of values from your entire loop.

If you used `return i`, it would just return a single `int` value.  In your case, this would cause a compiler error, as the return type of your method is `IEnumerable<int>`, not `int`.

In this specific example, I would personally just return `lstNumbers` instead of using the iterator.  You could rewrite this without the list, though, as:

```
public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateList()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
    yield return 4;
    yield return 5;
}
```

Or even:

```
public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateList()
{
    for (int i=1;i<=5;++i)
        yield return i;
}
```

This is very handy when you're making a class which you want to act like a collection.  Implementing `IEnumerable<T>` by hand for a custom type often requires making a custom class, etc.  Prior to iterators, this required a lot of code, as shown in this [old sample for implementing a custom collection in C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307484).

Comment: Is Yield still preferred with .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5?

Comment: Or even use `return Enumerable.Range(1,5);`

Comment: @RKh It depends on what you're doing.  It's still used, certainly, but it's not something that most people need to use a *lot*.  It's not deprecated or anything though.

Comment: @RKh It's not a matter of preference - if you're implementing something you want to allow people to use as a sequence, then it's a very nice way to do it.

Comment: @ReedCopsey If the collection has random values, will Yield return a sorted sequence? How it works for string values?

Comment: @RKh No - it returns the values in the order it's called.  If you want to order them, you can order later.  Yield will work on strings the same way - it will "yield" each string each time you do a yield return.

Comment: @ReedCopsey This means it will return the sequence in which items are inserted in the List.

Comment: @RKh Yes, in this case, since the list's enumerator returns them in this order, as you're calling Add.  If you inserted (via Insert) in the middle of the list, it would return the items in the order they existed in the list when you enumerated it.

Comment: @KKh Yes - the code above is kind of silly.  As I said, you could just return the list itself (since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`).  There isn't really a reason to use `yield return` just to return values of a collection.  It's more useful when you're implementing your own collection type.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Please share any link showing Custom Collection Class.

Answer (score 2):

As Reed says using `yield` allows you to implement an iterator. The major advantage of an iterator is that it allows lazy evaluation. I.e. it doesn't have to materialize the entire result unless needed.

Consider `Directory.GetFiles` from the BCL. It returns `string[]`. I.e. it has to get all the files and put the names in an array before it returns. In contrast `Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns `IEnumerable<string>`. I.e. the caller is responsible for handling the result set. That means that the caller can opt out of enumerating the collection at any point.

Comment: What do you mean by: "it doesn't have to materialize the entire result unless needed"?

Comment: If you're returning an array, you need to fill the entire array before you can return it. With iterators you return one element at a time and thus whatever work you need to do in order to get the elements can be done as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `yield` keyword will make the compiler turn the function into an enumerator object.

The `yield return` statement doesn't simply exit the function and return one value, it leaves the code in a state so that it can be resumed at that point when the next value is requested from the enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return just i as i is an int and not an IEnumerable.  It won't even compile.  You could have returned lstNumbers as that implements the interface of IEnumerable.

I prefer yield return since the compiler will handle building the enumerable and not having to build the list in the first place.  So for me if I have something that is already implementing the interface then I return that if I have to build it and not use it else where then I yield return.